# Regular expression for auto-complete

Tags: regex

I have a list of phrases that consist of words which can be sperated by spaces, hyphens, camelCase or PascalCase. I want to be able to filter those phrases by typing only few letters of each word, and maybe skipping some of the words. 
For those familiar with JetBrains' IDEs, it's similar to the way code completion works there. I want to simulate that behavior for general purpose, and not just for writing code in IDEs. (General purpose being using it in a website to filter phrases, maybe use it with Bash to get a list of files with just typing some of the first letters of the file's words, or some of its words as I said). This is very convenient tool that I'm using a lot (in JetBrains')!

**Example**:

Giving the following phrases:

- `LoremIpsumDolor`
- `sitAmetConsectetur`
- `adipisicing-elit-sed`
- `Do Eiusmod Tempor incididunt`

Here are some typical words I'd like to filter by:

- `lodo` -> gives back `LoremIpsumDolor` (Note the case insensitivity here, that's the way I want it)
- `dotemporinc` -> gives back `Do Eiusmod Tempor incididunt`
- `Do` -> gives back `LoremIpsumDolor` and `Do Eiusmod Tempor incididunt`
- `ac` -> gives back `sitAmetConsectetur`

I've been thinking about how to implement this kind of functionality, and the best I could come up with is that typing the word to filter by - say `lodo` from example 1, will generate a regular expression constructed from the letters of the word, separated by some additional expression to form the whole regular expression... Then it will test each phrase in the list against that regular expression, and return only those that match.

I thought about maybe splitting the word (`lodo`) into letters, and putting the following regexp between each letter (at the very beginning and at the very end): `([a-zA-Z][a-z]*)*`, (this solution, if it will work, assumes all phrases are camel\PascalCased, but the full solution must include the other cases as well). This will result in the following regexp:
`^([a-zA-Z][a-z]*)*[lL]([a-zA-Z][a-z]*)*[oO]([a-zA-Z][a-z]*)*[dD]([a-zA-Z][a-z]*)*[oO]([a-zA-Z][a-z]*)*$`

Obviously, this has some huge flaws deriving from backtracking, and to be more particular, I think (but defiantly not sure), that if I can disable backtracking on the inner star expression in `([a-zA-Z][a-z]*)*`, keeping only the backtracking of the outer star, it should work.

I hope I explained myself well enough. Maybe there is a known solution to this problem, then I'd love to hear it.

Comment: Sorry I can't be of more help, but these don't seem like ***regular*** phrases that ***regular*** expressions would be right to solve with. [Relevant XKCD](http://xkcd.com/1171/)...

Comment: Why regex? I would probably draft you a solution, but such would be too long to explain it with. Also, state the regex engine or implementation you're running it with, please.

Comment: @Sam I'm not 100% that regular expressions will help solve this problem, but then again, I'd be happy to hear other suggestions. At the bottom line, I just want to simulate the functionality of the JetBrains IDEs for code completion.

Comment: @Unihedron, there is not a particular engine I'm using, this could be of help in many scenarios.. most common may be on the web (Javascript's engine then), but it can also be on Unix's Bash's console as I stated, and maybe others.. if the problem can be solved with regexp I'd expect the solution to be as generic as possible.

Comment: you need a set of Automata to help you out instead of regex. you should not expect intelligence from regex.

Comment: @HuStmpHrrr I don't expect intelligence from it, I'm willing to put the "intelligence" manually in it if it's possible. And by that I mean, if there is a way to control the regexp behavior, like disabling backtracking as I said (but not entirely disable it), it will probably help.

Comment: unfortunately, i don't see any hope by just using regex to solve this problem. a lot of exceptions could be found right after you finish your implementation. the rules to describe the string fragmentation is too ambiguous.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After thinking about it for couple of hours I've crafted a solution using regular expression, and I really think this is a very suitable solution to the problem, and it's really not that hard.

My solution currently deals only with camelCase and PascalCase phrases (i.e. it can filter correctly only phrases written with camelCase or PascalCase), but adapting it to other cases should be easy enough. For the time being, these cases are good enough.

So, here is what I came up with:

Given a word, say `lodo` from my examples above, one should realize that for each letter in the given word (`l` `o` `d` `o`), it can be either the first letter of a word (means that it should match an uppercase letter, or if it's the first word, it may also be lower case), or it is next letter in a word we previously found (means it's lowercase, and it should be tried for a match right after we already found a previous letter).
We should also take into account the behavior of regular expression, and to be precise, the evalutaion order of sub-expressions. We will use the fact that in an *or* expression(`|`), the left hand side is tried first, and that in an expression of the form `e*?` (javascript), it will find the smallest possible match (as opposed to omitting the question mark, and in that case it will consume the largest characters possible, then we might get into backtracking situation, which is bad for us).

So, let's construct the regexp. For each character *c*, we construct:

- If *c* is our first letter (in `lodo` it means `l`), then:

  - For *c* to match the first letter of the first word, it can be lowercase, we construct: `(^c)`
  - Otherwise it must be the first letter of some other word, and must be uppercase, we construct: `C`
  - **Our expression for the first letter: `(^c|C)`**
- Otherwise:

  - We want to first test if our letter is a continuation of a word we already found the beginning of. So again, our *c* letter (in `lodo` this argument is valid for any of `o` `d` `o`) in this case must be lowercase, and we construct `(c)`
  - Otherwise, *c* must be the first letter in a new word, which means it must be uppercase, and we also must take into account the regex we constructed for previous letters, so we must consume the entire word we are currently at, and then try to consume other words, but we give precedence to our uppercase `c` letter (hope this explanation was clear). For this all scenario, we construct
    `[a-z]*([A-Z][a-z]*)*?C`. (`[a-z]*` for consuming the remaining letters of the current word, and `([A-Z][a-z]*)*?` for trying to consume other words, if it happens that `C` is not the first letter of our next word (remember that it can be the next letter of 2 words ahead and so... this is my requirement))
  - **Our expression for any non-first letters: `(c|([a-z]*([A-Z][a-z]*)*?C))`**

So, with those instructions, we can build a regular expression for our beloved `lodo`, and this is what we should get: `(^l|L)(o|([a-z]*([A-Z][a-z]*)*?O))(d|([a-z]*([A-Z][a-z]*)*?D))(o|([a-z]*([A-Z][a-z]*)*?O))`

I have tested it with some words on an AngularJS project, and it seem to work great. I will improve it to take into account other cases, but I don't think it should be very hard.

**UPDATE**

Playing with it a little bit, I adapted it to take into account what I consider most of the possible cases of word seperation detection (via camelCase, PascalCase, spaces, hyphens, underscores, and actually any seperator that is not an alphabet character). This made the regex a lot more concise, and maybe even a little bit more efficient. I removed most of the hassle that I explained in my original answer, and replaced all the `[a-z]*([A-Z][a-z]*)*?` sub-expressions with only `.*?`, which works because it does not consume characters until it have no choice, which is better to the approach to first consume the characters and then backtrack.

For each character *c*, we now construct the expression: `(c|.*?(C|[^a-zA-Z]c))`. This, however, may or may not introduce a little backtracking (depending on the optimization of the engine - if it constructs automaton from the regex, and if it minimizes it), in the case where the next character is non-alphabet, and the next character after it is not the desired lowercase letter, then it will back track from the `[^a-zA-Z]c` expression, to the `.*?` expression, then consume (again) the non-alphabet character (the first one), and keep on.. (it means, in this case we might consume that character twice - in `[^a-zA-Z]`, and in `.*?`, but this may not be the case if the engine optimizes the automaton).

The constructed expression of `lodo` will be now:
 `^(l|.*?(L|[^a-zA-Z]l))(o|.*?(O|[^a-zA-Z]o))(d|.*?(D|[^a-zA-Z]d))(o|.*?(O|[^a-zA-Z]o))`.

I know that my question did not gain popularity, but I'm writing the solutions I came up with for future reference (even if it's only for me).

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution in Javascript, which is super simple compared to using autocomplete using tries.

```
const searchData = searchText => {
  const regex = new RegExp(searchText, 'gi');
  return new Promise(resolve => resolve(topMovies.filter(m => m.title.match(regex))))
};

const topMovies = [{title: "The Shawshank Redemption (1994)", rating: 9.2   },{title: "The Godfather (1972)", rating: 9.2   },{title: "The Godfather: Part II (1974)", rating: 9.0  },{title: "The Dark Knight (2008)", rating: 9.0 },{title: "12 Angry Men (1957)", rating: 8.9    },{title: "Schindler's List (1993)", rating: 8.9    },{title: "The Lord of the Rings: The Return of the King (2003)", rating: 8.9   },{title: "Pulp Fiction (1994)", rating: 8.9    },{title: "The Good, the Bad and the Ugly (1966)", rating: 8.8  },{title: "Fight Club (1999)", rating: 8.8  },{title: "The Lord of the Rings: The Fellowship of the Ring (2001)", rating: 8.8   },{title: "Forrest Gump (1994)", rating: 8.7    },{title: "Star Wars: Episode V - The Empire Strikes Back (1980)", rating: 8.7  },{title: "Inception (2010)", rating: 8.7   },{title: "The Lord of the Rings: The Two Towers (2002)", rating: 8.7   },{title: "One Flew Over the Cuckoo's Nest (1975)", rating: 8.7 },{title: "Goodfellas (1990)", rating: 8.7  },{title: "The Matrix (1999)", rating: 8.6  },{title: "Seven Samurai (1954)", rating: 8.6   },{title: "City of God (2002)", rating: 8.6 },{title: "Star Wars: Episode IV - A New Hope (1977)", rating: 8.6  },{title: "Se7en (1995)", rating: 8.6   },{title: "The Silence of the Lambs (1991)", rating: 8.6    },{title: "It's a Wonderful Life (1946)", rating: 8.6   },{title: "Life Is Beautiful (1997)", rating: 8.6   },{title: "The Usual Suspects (1995)", rating: 8.5  },{title: "Spirited Away (2001)", rating: 8.5   },{title: "Saving Private Ryan (1998)", rating: 8.5 },{title: "Léon: The Professional (1994)", rating: 8.5  },{title: "Avengers: Infinity War (2018)", rating: 8.5  },{title: "The Green Mile (1999)", rating: 8.5  },{title: "Interstellar (2014)", rating: 8.5    },{title: "American History X (1998)", rating: 8.5  },{title: "Psycho (1960)", rating: 8.5  },{title: "City Lights (1931)", rating: 8.5 },{title: "Once Upon a Time in the West (1968)", rating: 8.5    },{title: "Casablanca (1942)", rating: 8.5  },{title: "Modern Times (1936)", rating: 8.5    },{title: "The Intouchables (2011)", rating: 8.5    },{title: "The Pianist (2002)", rating: 8.5 },{title: "The Departed (2006)", rating: 8.5    },{title: "Terminator 2 (1991)", rating: 8.5    },{title: "Back to the Future (1985)", rating: 8.5  },{title: "Rear Window (1954)", rating: 8.5 },{title: "Raiders of the Lost Ark (1981)", rating: 8.5 },{title: "Whiplash (2014)", rating: 8.5    },{title: "Gladiator (2000)", rating: 8.5   },{title: "The Lion King (1994)", rating: 8.5   },{title: "The Prestige (2006)", rating: 8.5    },{title: "Memento (2000)", rating: 8.4 }];

const searchInputElement = document.querySelector('.search-input');
    const resultsElement = document.querySelector('.results');

    // Convert search results into UI suggestions
    function showSearchResults(searchQuery) {
        searchData(searchQuery).then(results => {
            const html = results.map(movie => `
      <li>
        <span class="title">${movie.title}</span>
        <span class="rating">${movie.rating}</span>
      </li>
    `);

            resultsElement.innerHTML = html.join('');
        });
    }

    // Pass 
    function handleChange() {
        return showSearchResults(this.value);
    }

    // Register for both events
    searchInputElement.addEventListener('change', handleChange);
    searchInputElement.addEventListener('keyup', handleChange);


//HTML
<form class="search-form">
    <input type="text" class="search-input" placeholder="Start typing a movie title...">
    <ul class="results"></ul>
</form>
```

Comment: This does not answer my original question. Your solution is very simple indeed, but it is not suitable for IDE-like autocomplete as it does not allow the user to compose a search query which consist of parts of multiple words, and does not take into account the concept of a "word" at all. Thanks for your effort though.

Comment: `searchData` takes in 1 single string from a movie title, if you want multiple words, it is not rocket science. all you have to write your own for loop and loop through the words. this is an autocomplete I use all the time. if it's not working for you, it's probably you don't understand the code.