# RegEx using pattern for an input field in HTML5, not working

Tags: javascript, regex, reactjs

This is a React JS application. The field is to allow ONLY three possible options: CREDIT, DEBIT. Nothing else should be allowed.

Here is my JS code...

```
        <AutoCompleteInput
            name="type"
            required="required"
            defaultValue={type}
            pattern="\bCREDIT\b|\bDEBIT\b"
            maxLength="6"
            title="Type must be CREDIT or DEBIT."
        />
```

As you can see, I am using the React AutoCompleteInput component so there is a pull-down menu with the three options and the user can select them from the pull down menu.  However, the user can also type in the options.

The way the regular expression is written on the pattern above the user must type the words in uppercase, if they type it in lowercase the entries are not valid.  How can make that regex case insensitive?

The regex testers have the flag that I can select it from the pull down menu and it will add the /i to my regex

```
/(\bCREDIT\b|\bDEBIT\b)\i
```

but that expression does not work on my code. Again, how can I make my regex case insensitive?  This (?i) does not work either.  There most be a way but I cannot figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

With the information on this question... [Regular expression for auto-complete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25916586/regular-expression-for-auto-complete)

I was able to get the solution I was looking for.  It is long and messy but it works.  this is the final regex for my question above.

```
^(c|.*?(C|[^a-zA-Z]c))(r|.*?(R|[^a-zA-Z]r))(e|.*?(E|[^a-zA-Z]e))(d|.*?(D|[^a-zA-Z]d))(i|.*?(I|[^a-zA-Z]i))(t|.*?(T|[^a-zA-Z]t))|(d|.*?(D|[^a-zA-Z]d))(e|.*?(E|[^a-zA-Z]e))(b|.*?(B|[^a-zA-Z]b))(i|.*?(I|[^a-zA-Z]i))(t|.*?(T|[^a-zA-Z]t))"
```